# Find distance of one graph from another in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two curves in Matlab.

Curve A:

```
x1 = [128 192   256 384 512 704 1024 1472 2048 2880 4096 5824 8192 11584 16384 23168];
y1 = [0.62 0.51 0.43 0.35 0.3 0.26 0.22 0.18 0.15 0.13 0.11 0.09 0.08 0.06 0.05 0.05];
```

Curve B:

```
x2 = [16 24 32 48 64 88 128 184 256 360 512 728 1024 1448 2048 2896];
y2 = [1.94 1.54 1.33 1.15 0.97 0.86 0.71 0.59 0.5 0.42 0.36 0.3 0.25 0.21 0.18 0.15];
```

After drawing both curves (x-axis exponentially) in the same plot:

```
semilogx(x1,y1,'-o')
hold on
semilogx(x2,y2,'-o')
```

I have found that B curve is above A curve. But I want to shift B to the left so that B curve overlaps A curve. So the question is, what amount (right to left) I need to shift B curve to overlap A curve?

Some clue: Maybe need to count the vertical distance (for all match points) from B to A (interpolation) and square the distance and sum them all up and find the value of Alpha. How can I do it in Matlab?

Comment: Looking at the data, it seems that y1<y2. Did you try y1=y1+0.5 before drawing?

Comment: no! this will make them further away from each other. i want to calculate the distance (interpolation).

Comment: What is the expected output in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find the desired shift by first finding what values of `x2` would move the curve B exactly on top of curve A. This can be achieved by resampling curve A at points corresponding to the y-coordinates of the points in curve B. The following code illustrates this.

Since you plot the x-axis in log-domain, I assume that you want to shift `log10(x2)`. So the x-points on your shifted curve be will be `log10(x2) + shift` instead of `log10(x2 + shift)`.

```
% find the subset of y2 which is within the range of y1
idxCommonB = find((y2 <= max(y1)) & (y2 >= min(y1)));
y2c = y2(idxCommonB);
x2c = x2(idxCommonB);

% for each point on curve B, find a new x2 that would move the point on
% curve A
% We use interp1 function for resample the curve. This function requires
% all the points in the domain to be unique. So find the unique elements in
% y1.
[y1_unique,iUnique] = unique(y1);
x2c_desired = interp1(y1_unique, x1(iUnique), y2c, 'linear');

% find the average distance between the desired and given curves
x2_logshift = mean(log10(x2c_desired) - log10(x2c));

% Display the result
fprintf('Required shift in log10(x2) is %f.\n', x2_logshift);
% Required shift in log10(x2) is -0.126954.    

% plot to verify the estimate
figure;
plot(log10(x1),y1,'-o')
hold on
plot(log10(x2),y2,'-o')
plot(log10(x2)+x2_logshift,y2,':*')
grid on;
legend({'A', 'B', 'Shifted B'});
set(gca, 'FontSize', 12);
```

[image: results]

Comment: This solution looks excellent but i have few questions this plot must answer.
1. How much i need to shift the red curve so that it overlaps the blue curve. is it -0.126? shell it be negative? can i solve this without log10?
2. On x-axis i  need to draw the graph (exponentially) using semilogx() function to show the x-axis clearly

Comment: Yes, the red curve needs to be shifted by -0.126 in log-domain to match the blue curve. The negative sign means that the shift is towards left. In my opinion the shift ought to be performed in log-domain, as otherwise the match between the two curves would be poor. Finally, you can easily use `semilogx` for the plot. Just keep in mind that a shift in log-scale is equivalent to multiplication in linear-scale. So, for example, the shifted red curve can be plotted by: `semilogx(x2*10^x2_logshift, y2)`.

Comment: Just one more thought. In my real case. the x-axis is the number of judgments and y-axis is the average confidence interval. so how can i relate -0.126 with the number of judgments? can i say 0.126 average judgments are required to shift B curve to have the same results as A curve? does it sounds right? thanks

Comment: No. Remember that we estimated the shift in log-domain. So the offset is multiplicative, not additive. It would be more correct to say that curve A takes `10^-0.126 = 0.75` times as many judgements as curve B (or 25% fewer than curve B). Or curve B takes `10^0.126 = 1.33` times as many judgements as curve A for the same confidence interval (or 33% more than curve A).

Comment: So, if we multiply 0.75 judgments with B then we will have the same confidence interval as A.

Comment: Yes. You should just try it.